# .htaccess redirect remove "?_route_=" form URL

Tags: .htaccess

I am using .htaccess redirect in my website. I am using those code

> Redirect /addgiftmr/widgetjs.aspx https://www.mysite.com/

But when redirect, it is adding extra word. I am getting url as [https://www.mysite.com/?*route*=addgiftmr/widgetjs.aspx](https://www.mysite.com/?_route_=addgiftmr/widgetjs.aspx)

how can I remove **?*route*=addgiftmr/widgetjs.aspx** form link?

Comment: Do you have any rewriterules or a CMS that could possible cause this?

Comment: Can you post your current .htaccess content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it in `.htaccess` if `mod-rewrite` is installed. The advantage of `mod-rewrite` is that it is easier to expand later if you want to use more complex rules.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^addgiftmr/widgetjs.aspx https://www.mysite.com/ [L,R]
```